# How to bring to the front form with focus in textbox or any other control in that form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Split Container that have Panel 1 (left, with menu) and Panel 2 (right, where I load the child forms), in the menu I have a button that opens a new child form. It only allows one instance of the window at a time, not duplicates.

The last form that I open always stays in front of the Panel 2, even when the focus is on the form in back.

How do I bring the back from to front when I focus a control in it?

Function that open the form

```
private void AddFormInPanel(object formChild)
{
    Form fh = formChild as Form;
    Form existe = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form>().Where(pre => pre.Name == fh.Name.ToString()).SingleOrDefault<Form>();
    if (existe == null)
    {
        fh.TopLevel = false;
        this.splitContainer.Panel2.Controls.Add(fh);
        this.splitContainer.Panel2.Tag = fh;
        fh.BringToFront();
        fh.Show();
    }
}
```

Call to the function

```
private void buttonForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddFormInPanel(new Form1());
        }
private void buttonForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddFormInPanel(new Form2());
        }
```

In this example, i Have focused the textbox Name, but the form still in back.
Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fojwS.jpg

Comment: even after `fh.BringToFront();` is it in the back.?

Comment: When I press the button to load the form, load in the front. When I have the 2 children loaded, when changing between one and another if I enter the textbox of the one that is behind, it does not go to the front, look at the image.

Comment: You cannot `BringToFront();` a control you haven't shown. Move `fh.BringToFront();` after `fh.Show();` + This: `AddFormInPanel(new Form1());` is a mistake, you'll find out soon enough. I suggest to use UserControls instead of Forms.

Comment: Hi Jimi, can you tellme more about UserControls instead of Forms ? Thanks.

Comment: The best thing you can do is to create a new Class Library Project where you add a UserControl. Or `Project -> Add User Control` to add a new one to an existing Solution/Project. A UserControl has a designer, exactly as a Form, but it can live on its own, it must be owned by a Form, as a standard control. If you need to group specific functionalities in a single component, a UserControl is the tool of choice. You can consider it, in a way, as a borderless Form. Get accustomed to it, it's quite useful.

Comment: Adding a UserControl as a Class Library Project to an existing Solution, lets you debug your UserControl more easily. When you add a Class Library Project, you'll find your UserControl in the Toolbox - in its own dedicated *space* - so you can drop it on any Form as standard controls.

Comment: Btw, when you want to *ping* someone, it's prefereable to prefix the nickname with `@`. I wasn't notified of your comment.

Comment: Thank You @Jimi , I will try to do it with User Controls, Do you have an example of how to use it?